# Detect boundedness of Riemann tensor by finitely many scalar observables

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold without boundary. Let $\mathrm{R}(M)$ be the space of Riemannian metrics on it.

A scalar observable is a continuous function $f:\mathrm{R}(M)\to C^\infty(M, \mathbb{R})$ such that $f(\psi^*g)(p)=f(\psi(p))$ for any diffeomorphism $\psi:M\to M$ and any metric $g$.

Are there finitely many scalar observables $f_1,\dots,f_n$ such that the Riemann tensor of $g$ is bounded iff $f_1(g),\dots,f_n(g)$ are all bounded functions?

P. S. If there is finitely many such scalar observables they can be reduced to just one by taking the sum of the squares but I thought this framing might be more natural.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the question, but can't one just take $f = |\mathrm{Riem}|^2$?

Comment: Terry's comment suffices to answer the OP's question, but it is interesting to note that in the Lorentzian case, the answer is 'no':  There are non-flat metrics of signature (2,1) such that all invariant scalar polynomials in the curvature and its covariant derivatives vanish identically.  For example $$g = \mathrm{d}y^2 - 4\, \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}z - 4\bigl(h(x,y)+k(x,y)z\bigr)\,\mathrm{d}x^2$$ is such a metric for any smooth functions $h$ and $k$, and $g$ is actually flat only if $k_y=h_{yy}=0$.